# I'm resigning after only a few months due to issues with my supervisor. Other colleagues are questioning why. Should I tell them the truth?

Tags: colleagues, resignation, manager, gossip

As per the title, I had a really tough time working with my boss and have issues with them. Both personally and professionally. Thus, I have decided to resign after only working a few months here despite the extremely good salary.

Now, my other colleagues (not my direct teammates, who knew the reason immediately as they also hate our manager) have asked why I have decided to resign so quickly.

Should I tell them the truth? I'm worried this might somehow further hurt my teammates' relationship with my boss or cause office gossip to spread like wildfire. Although I have issues with my boss, they don't deserve the treatment of the whole department talking behind their back. My boss was newly appointed so I kind of sympathise with them not being experienced in being a manager.

Should I lie with something like I don't find the job scope interesting? What should I do?

Comment: Not that it should encourage you to tell them the truth, but if they're reaching out to you like this, there is a fair chance they already know/suspect the truth.

Comment: It's none of their business. They may find out through the rumor mill anyway, but you are in no way obliged to answer the question. "I'm looking for a change" is always a good evasive answer

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to lie, just say you found a better opportunity. You don't have to give any reason why you don't like your current job.

Comment: The problem with the "better opportunity" answer is that anyone with half a clue understands that people don't leave jobs for something worse, which makes it code for "this place sucks and I want out."  Someone wanting out three months in is usually an indicator that something's wrong.

Comment: yep that's true but at the same time no one's going to push you to explain why you don't like your workplace or demand an additional reason for leaving

Answer (score 3):

I think its better to not tell the reason as it might create pre-concieved opinion about the manager and everyone might avoid working under him/her. Let them have their own experience and decide for themselves.

You can tell the job didn't worked out for you. If the manager is bad then sooner or later everyone is going to get to know this anyway.

Edit:

Reiterating what I said in the comments below about the fact that manager is new and hated by the team working under him/her.

@virolino The answer should take into account about the fact that manager is new. If the entire team hates the manager sooner or later he/she is going to be fired anyway and if OP has accepted the new job there is no point in discussing the employment at current company. Best for OP is to move on.

Comment: Don’t know why this was downvoted. It answered the question and gave reasons.

Comment: @Damila - Because it's a bad response?

Comment: @dwjohnston Can you please explain how it's a bad response?

Comment: Because the least of OP's worries is the reputation of the bad boss. That is why it is a bad answer. Also, "pre-concieved" is not a good word to be associated with what happens AFTER the bad experience.

Comment: So if OP doesn't cares about managers reputation it's justified to tell everyone about your experience with a person and jeopardize their career irrespective how others might feel about working under him? OP found a new job and doesn't have any incentive in explaining the reason behind quitting.

Comment: @virolino only the team members working under the manager had the experience so far as the manager is new. What if the manager's behavior was limited to the current team?

Comment: @newguy: you are missing the point. Your answer should concentrate on what the OP should do, not about the boss being new - new and bad enough to be hated by the entire team.

Comment: @virolino the answer already mentions what OP should do. The should take into account about the fact that manager is new. If the entire team hates him sooner or later he is going to be fired anyway and if OP has accepted the new job there is no point in discussing the employment at current company.

Answer (score 1):

> As per the title, I had a really tough time working with my boss and have issues with him/her. Both personally and professionally. Thus, I have decided to resign after only working a few months here despite the extremely good salary.

Personal issues -> I will assume it happened in the workplace and not outside.

> Not my direct teammates, who knew the reason immediately as they also hate our manager

-> if everybody in your team "Hate" (which is strong word) the manager, it is likely that a lot of people in the company are aware of this.

> I'm worried this might somehow further hurt my teammates' relationship with my boss

-> I don't see why you leaving because of a bad relationship will affect the relationship of others.

> or cause office gossip to spread like wildfire.

-> Everybody gossips in office, it is normal.

It seems you already answer the question yourself :

> My boss was newly appointed so I kind of empathise with him/her not being experienced in being a manager.

-> just reply the Truth : "it seems that my manager is new on the job, and we didn't 'click' because of the working ways he follows, so I decided to find another job where I can more in synch with my direct manager"